# Unable to post tweets from another viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am Using Outh to add Twitter to my app

Basically I am using two different `UIViewControllers`.

1. `SettingViewcontroller`
2. `DetailViewcontroller`

My app is login to twitter account with `SettingViewcontroller`.

If I use only one `UIViewController`, I am able to post the tweets. But as per my requirement, I need post from `DetailViewcontroller`. I also declare my consumer and secret in `DetailView`'s method but tweets are not posting to twitter from this `UIViewController`.

login From  SettingViewcontroller.

```
      - (void)switchAction1:(UISwitch*)sender
     {


      if (sender.on) {

   if(_engine) 
       return;

   _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];


   _engine.consumerKey = @"###";
    _engine.consumerSecret = @"###";



    UIViewController *controller = [SA_OAuthTwitterController          
    controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine: _engine delegate: self];
     [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];



      }
    if(!sender.on)
   { 


  NSlog(@"logout");


    }
```

Posting tweets From Detailviewconroller

```
if(buttonIndex == 1)
{

    if(_engine!=nil) 
    { 
        NSLog(@"engine availble");
        NSString *str=@"hai twitterrrrrrrrrrr";
        [_engine sendUpdate:str];

    }



    else {
        NSLog(@"engine not availble");


    }
```

Comment: Please add code. There can be multiple things that could have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same object in which you login.(ie)You should use the same object thru which u login in setting controller for Posting tweet in Detail controller

Comment: okay.Should I have to declare consumer key and consumer secret in DetailViewcontroller also?

Comment: No need.Bcz u initialized all the data during tat login itselt

Comment: Same issue. _engine is not available here. Because this line declaring  self as delegate. _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];

Comment: U should not initialize again.U should use the obj which was initialized in previous controller (ie: ur settingsController).Pass tat obj to detailviewcontroller and use that for calling sendUpdate: method